# Reading JSON map structure via spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

If I have the following JSON structure returned by my REST service:

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "id" : "baz"
   }
   "qux" : {
      "id" : "toto"
   }
}
```

To me it looks like a map structure. I am not sure how I can read this using spring boot (via Jackson).

I have defined my JSON bind class like so:

```
public class Foos {

   private Map<String, Foo> fooInstances;

   private void setFooInstances(Map<String, Foo> fooInstances) {
      this.fooInstances = fooInstances;
   }

   private Map<String, Foo> getFooInstances() {
      return fooInstances;
   }

}
```

And a Foo instance looks like so:

```
public class Foo {

   private String id;


   private void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   private String getId() {
      return id;
   }

}
```

The spring code for making the request is like so:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Foos> responseEntity = (ResponseEntity<Foos>) template.getForEntity(serviceEndpointURL, Foos.class);
```

I originally had a START_OBJECT error which I fixed by creating the Foos class with the corresponding map and now I don't get an error. Instead I get a populated ResponseEntity, with a 'Foos' instance, but the map is null. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are you using for JSON mapping? Jackson or Gson? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: Apologies. It's via Jackson. Spring boot uses Jackson JSON library.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I don't see any annotations in  your class file

Comment: Perhaps you should initialize your map to an empty instance of a `Map` implementation like `new HashMap();`

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with Jackson. What annotations should I be using? I got one example working before with no bindings (as per this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

Comment: I initialized the map there, but it is empty after the JSON is processed.

Comment: Also, your JSON input seems not logical. If you want to know what your input JSON should be, you can for example create an instance of `Foos`, populate it and return it in a dummy controller method. Then, see what JSON is produced as output.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the JSON format. Surely there is a way to parse it?

Comment: With that JSON as input, you can only parse an object which contains one instance of `Foo`.

Comment: I've updated the input now, I had a mistake in the input JSON. It's now correct.

Comment: so there will be multiple child nodes with different names like `foo`, `qux`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your Foos class like this

```
public class Foos {

@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
return this.properties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.properties.put(name, value);
}
}
```

You can typecast from `Object` to `Foo` from the map.

Let me know if you have any questions!!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and let you know.

Comment: Happy to help!!